# How do I import variables from .env in Intellij IDEA Protractor (JS) debug?

Tags: intellij-idea, protractor

I have recently introduced a .env file to a Typescript Protractor project. I installed `dotenv` package, and run `dotenv.config()` at the very top of the protractor config file. When executed from console, all works as expected, .env is loaded, everyone's happy.

However when I execute from IntelliJ IDEA's debug tool (configured for Protractor), the .env file doesn't load - even though the code goes through `dotenv.config()`.

I can work around by setting env variables in the debug config, but that has to be done manually, and I would prefer to source these values from the .env file automatically (`source .env` in a "before launch" script doesn't help either).

Can this be done using just Cucumber.js package? If not, which package would help?

Comment: what run configuration do you use to run your tests, what working directory is set there? please make sure that it's the same as you use to run tests in console, to make sure that the `.env` file is loaded

Comment: It is the same config file. I am sure that the compiler passes through `dotenv.config()` command, because I put a breakpoint there, and it triggered when expected. However the `.env` file was NOT loaded